# DataGridView - Fill DataSet with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview, dataset

I want a DataSet get filled with a particular piece of Xml. This is the Xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Courses>
    <Course id="3306">
        <Student>One</Student>
        <Student>Two</Student>
        <Student>Three</Student>
        <Student>Four</Student>
    </Course>
</Courses>
```

Of course there will be more `<Course>`-Tags. Now I want one Course to fill the DataSet who shows itself in a DataGridView.
 
E. g. "Show all Students WHERE Course-ID == '3306' "  
 
Now I thought about Linq but I really do not know how to to it. Maybe Linq is a wrong start... 
For other "unfiltered" Lists I use

```
string filePath = "AllStudents.Xml";
dsCourseList.ReadXml(filePath);
dgvCourseList.DataSource = dsCourseList; //DataSet
dgvCourseList.DataMember = "Student";
```

Maybe someone could help me.

Comment: Why use a `Dataset` when you can bind directly to  the anonymous types from the linq query?

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint, I will try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind directly to the LINQ object.

```
var results = myCourses.Where(c=>c.ID == courseId);

dgvCourseList.DataSource = results.ToList();
```

Comment: What exactly would be "myCourses"?

Comment: `myCourses` would be your parsed xml data.